# BigQuery table functions with tables as arguments or return values

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I would like to create a function that passes a table and filters it, but it doesn't work!

statement 1 define function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION sandobx.func(_t array<STRUCT<`id` INT64, `name` STRING>>)
AS (
  select * from unnest(_t)
);
```

statement 2 call function

```
with t AS (
              SELECT *
                FROM UNNEST([
                       Struct(
                         1 as id, "taro" as name
                         "taro" as name
                       ),
                       (2, 'jiro')
                     ])
            )

SELECT * FROM sandobx.func(t)
```

I thought it would behave like a table since it is an array type, but it doesn't seem to be so